# How to save Salesforce Query Results to MySql database

Tags: salesforce, mule

I want to query Salesforce and save the results in a database. The first problem is that I find my payload is a ConsumerIterator.  How can I process these results to store in a database?

```
<flow name="process.accounts" processingStrategy="synchronous">
  <sfdc:select config-ref="MySQLDB" doc:name="Select Contact by Email">
    <sfdc:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT first_name,last_name,email 
   FROM      Contact WHERE  email=#[payload.email]]]></db:parameterized-
   query>
   </sfdc:select>
  </flow>

   <flow name="insert.contacts.to.audit" >
     <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="contact-audit"/>                                   
     <db:insert config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Save 
         Contact">
     <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into user_audit v 
               values(?,?,?)]]></db:parameterized-query>
     </db:insert>
   </flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mulesoft exchange provides many common integration patterns such as the one you seek.

https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/org.mule.templates/template-sfdc2db-account-bidirectional-sync/

use that template to quickly understand the how